# Django: Can't find template files. / App works without template files?

Tags: templates, python-2.7, shared-hosting, django-1.4

Yesterday I tried to edit a template in my django app and noticed that the template-file isn't even used (anymore). Even if I delete it the app will continue to work and changes I make in the file wont appear online. I couldn't find any other template file on my server, so could it be that Django imported it somehow or copied/saved it somewhere else?

The app is hosted on a shared host, with Python2.7, Django 1.4.5 and FCGI.

My settings.py looks like this:

```
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

#FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/polls'

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = 'http://ulli.cepheus.uberspace.de/static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = 'http://ulli.cepheus.uberspace.de/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/var/www/virtual/ulli/html/static",
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/template",
    "/template/polls",
    "/var/www/virtual/ulli/html/template/polls",
    "http://ulli.cepheus.uberspace.de/template",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Is it a core template or one that you made? Did you check all of the TEMPLATE_DIRS locations?

Comment: It is a template I made and uploaded. All the TEMPLATE_DIR location-urls lead to the same folder and yes, I checked them. Do you have any idea where my template might be "hiding"? :) Could it have to do with TEMPLATE_LOADERS?

Comment: The template HAS to be either in on of the locations under
TEMPLATE_DIRS
-- or --
somewhere that TEMPLATE_LOADERS looks(but from the looks of it, that is probably not the case

I would remove the duplicated entries that you have in the TEMPLATE_DIRS and also make sure that the template file that you are having difficulties with is not also part of one of your installed apps as well 

The last thing I can think of is that it is being cached by your browser or in some other manner

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but the template [might be cached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader).

Although, I don't see this cached loader in your settings. Might worth trying a restart anyway?